# asp.net cross domain form post: Parse Posted Data

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have an .aspx page which has the 'form' tag without the runat=server; it is posting some regular html form elements to another cross domain .aspx page. I can see inside the Firebug that the target page does get the posted data:

---

Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded

billingname FirstName LastName

btnpaynow   pay now

subtotal    870.0000

---

but when I try to use the following code nothing get written to the page.

```
    NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
    string subtotal = "NotSet";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["subtotal"]))
    {
        subtotal = nvc["subtotal"];
    }
    Response.Write("subttoal: " + subtotal);
```

note: same code works if I post to the same domain. So what's happening?

Comment: Please note that "ASP.NET" is a single word, with no spaces.

Comment: Oh, thanks for fixing that. And for fixing the bolded text. I need to be more careful here.

Comment: Oh, I think I needed to put the following in the posting form:

enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

Try Request["subtotal"]. 
Have you written method='post' at form tag?